# Leaflet Draw Error

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I'm trying to incorporate Leaflet. Draw on my map but I get the following error
I'm using version 1.7.1

```
Draw.Polyline.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined
    at initialize (Draw.Polyline.js:55)
    at new i (Class.js:22)
    at i.getModeHandlers (DrawToolbar.js:41)
    at i.addToolbar (Toolbar.js:89)
    at i.onAdd (Control.Draw.js:58)
    at i.addTo (Control.js:70)
    at i.addControl (Control.js:137)
    at maps:420
```

code

```
var mymap = L.map( 'map', {
            center: [-40.7972547, -62.9672901],
            minZoom: 2,
            zoom: 17,
            fadeAnimation: false,
            zoomAnimation: false,
            markerZoomAnimation: false
        });


        var base = L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: ['a','b','c']
        }).addTo( mymap ); 

        var myIcon = L.icon({
           iconUrl: '{{ asset("img/icon.png") }}',
        });

        var puntos = L.layerGroup();
        puntos.addTo(mymap);





var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
mymap.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
         featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
mymap.addControl(drawControl);
```

Comment: Please use text (in a code block) to present textual information. Right now, anyone wanting to reproduce your issue would need to retype all that code, and the error message isn't searchable, so no one else would be able to locate your question if they have the same problem.

Comment: Your code works for me, so there must be something wrong with your reference/link to `leaflet.draw` library.